# Clicking through to sublayers

Tags: html, css, z-index, transparency, sprite

I have an HTML image of a mannequin. An image map defines body parts. I have two divs on top of the image map, one to show the hover selection and one to show the current (active part). The problem I have is: when a part is marked as 'active', I reposition the background on the 'active' layer to show a highlighted background image (a sprite map which uses a different colour. When the 'active' state i displayed, I can't click through it's transparent parts to select a different part.

One possible solution would be to use [pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), but I wanted to keep it as compatible as possible.

Answer (score 0):

When i.e. a div has opacity:0; to make it transparent, it's still on top of other div's.
This way the div underneath won't be clickable.

This can be fixed by changing the display-mode of a div to hidden.
This way the div will be 'removed' and div's laying underneath will be clickable.

If you want to be able to click through transparent parts of an image, try using them as .PNG files.

-not sure if this might be helpful to you-

Comment: The background image is a PNG file. The sprite map with the 'active' states is overlaid on to the background below, so if I set it to visibility: hidden, I won't be able to see it (and it won't indicate the 'active' state)

Comment: Kind of hard to help you since i don't have a example. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to visualise the issue without being able to look at code or a diagram, but I've [tried something in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2tub2zf/6/) that may help.

In the example I've created, the 'hover' element starts off being unclickable where the 'active' element covers it (but is clickable where it is uncovered). After clicking the 'hover' element, its z-index property is altered so that it appears on top of the other elements. You can see it works because it is subsequently clickable everywhere.

Relevant jquery:

```
$( "#hover" ).css( "z-index", "2" );
```

I'm hoping this solution is helpful but, again, it's hard to tell if I've got the right idea without seeing a visual example of the original problem.

The idea behind this solution is you can rearrange the z-index values of elements upon clicks registering as many times as you need in order to make sure the relevant parts of the page are always clickable by the user.